# Mongoose One-To-Many without reference in "many" collection

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, one-to-many

I'm designing a project in which I need to store users and songs. Each user has his own songs (which technically can only reach 10,000).

My initial thought was to have a collection of `Users` and a collection of `Songs`. Inside the `User Schema`, I'll have an array referencing this users' songs:

```
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        username: String,
        ...
        songs: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Song" }],
        ...
    }
```

The songs collection won't have any reference to the user, since lots of users will obviously have the same songs saved and it makes more sense to simply have a collection with songs and no references to anything else.

After researching how to implement one-to-many relationships with Mongoose (without much luck) I came across MongoDB's documentation on these kinds of relationships:

> To avoid repetition of the publisher data, use references and keep the publisher information in a separate collection from the book collection.
>
> When using references, the growth of the relationships determine where to store the reference. If the number of books per publisher is small with limited growth, storing the book reference inside the publisher document may sometimes be useful. Otherwise, if the number of books per publisher is unbounded, this data model would lead to mutable, growing arrays.
>
> To avoid mutable, growing arrays, store the publisher reference inside the book document

They use a collection of publishers and books in their example, but the point is they recommend storing the reference in the "many" collection. I don't think I can do this with my project since there shouldn't be any connection between a song and which users have that song.

I'm not sure what I should do in this situation or how to design my project.. any help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is one-to-many?  I understand that a song can be owned by many users, which makes it many-to-many.

Comment: I mean technically that's true.. But the whole point was to completely separate the songs from the users. The collection of songs is independent and each user has his own array of references to songs.

Comment: You need to have a third collection like UserSong  to keep the relation between the user and song.

Comment: What would be the advantage of doing that?

Comment: It’s advantage is that your user and song collections won’t keep any references.